# CannotGetJdbcConnectionException returns for concorrunt threads

Tags: spring, oracle, jboss, jmeter

My web application returns following error for the last 4-5 threads among 50 of **concurrent** threads. When concurrent threads of 20-30, it works fine. 
application server - jboss eap 7
database - oracle 12c

> db properties

```
Initial Pool Size 
Min Pool Size 0
Max Pool Size 300
Flush Strategy FailingConnectionOnly
Pool Fair true
Pool Prefill false
Pool Use Strict Min false
Use Fast Fail false
Capacity Incrementer Class 
Capacity Incrementer Properties
```

> And also notice that database sessions are not varing rapidly. It behave in lazy way. when I hited 50 concurrent threads it increased 2-3 sessions only.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: 
IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
         at
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
         at
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:575)
         at
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:639)
         at
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:668)
         at
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:676)
         at
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:736)
         at
org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore.readAccessToken(JdbcTokenStore.java:156)
         at
org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices.loadAuthentication(DefaultTokenServices.java:207)
         at
org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager.authenticate(OAuth2AuthenticationManager.java:80)
         at
org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:117)
         at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
         at
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
         at
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
         at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
         at
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
         at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
         at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
         at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
         at
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
         at
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
         at
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
         at
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
         at
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
         at
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
         at
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
         at
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
         at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
         at
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
         at
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
         at
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
         at
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
         at
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
         at
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
         at
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
         at
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
         at
io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
         at
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
         at
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
         at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
         at
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
         at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
         at
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
         at
io.undertow.server.handlers.MetricsHandler.handleRequest(MetricsHandler.java:64)
         at
io.undertow.servlet.core.MetricsChainHandler.handleRequest(MetricsChainHandler.java:59)
         at
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
         at
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
         at
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
         at
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
         at
io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
         at
io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
         at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
         at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
         at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
         at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
         at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
         at
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
         at
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
         at
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
         at
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
         at
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
         at
org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
         at
org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
         at
org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
         at
org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
         at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:774)
         at
oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688)
         at
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
         at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
         at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
         at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
         at
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
         at
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
         at
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:153)
         at
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
         at
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
         at
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
         ... 64 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
         at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:523)
         at
oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:521)
         at
oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:660)
         at
oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:639)
         at
oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:189)
         at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:317)
         at
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1438)
         at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:518)
         ... 75 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection timed out, socket connect lapse 127273 ms. /192.168.43.134 1521 0 1 true
         at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:209)
         at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:161)
         at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:470)
         ... 82 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
         at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
         at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
         at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
         at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
         at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(Unknown Source)
         at
oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.<init>(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:81)
         at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:169)
         ... 84 more
```

Comment: Forget the JBoss logs.  Look in the *Oracle* logs, and see if there's an *Oracle* error corresponding to your "CannotGetJdbcConnectionException".  Please update your question: copy/paste the exact error message.

Comment: show your datasource configuration

Comment: @user7294900 please refer the edited question.

Comment: You aren't using a pool. The datasource you are using is `DriverManagerDataSource` which isn't a pool but opens a connection when needed. Use something like HikariCP for a proper connection pool. So basically your db properties are simply ignored.